# Compiling on CentOS & Fedora

Tags: stellar-core, new-developer

I have written spec files for packaging Stellar-core in the CentOS/Fedora and perhaps eventually RHEL. This works locally with the "make check" step however when I run "make check" on the remote Fedora build infrastructure one test 1/25 always fails.
See https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/philipmather/stellar-core/fedora-30-x86_64/01029769-stellar-core/builder-live.log.gz but the skinny version seems to be...

```
local:1/25/100%/5.5s 1  Creating temporary PostgreSQL database cluster in /tmp/pgtmp.aEVlJXyV
local:1/25/100%/5.6s 1  PostgreSQL enabled for tests using temporary database cluster
1   "LedgerTxnRoot prefetch" ledger/test/LedgerTxnTests.cpp:2162
1   ....<done>
1   "ItemFetcher fetches" overlay/test/ItemFetcherTests.cpp:76
local:1/25/100%/5.6s 1  ..................<done>
1   "subprocess fails" process/test/ProcessTests.cpp:49
1   .
1   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1   stellar-core test is a Catch v2.7.0 host application.
1   Run with -? for options
1   
1   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   subprocess fails
1   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   process/test/ProcessTests.cpp:49
1   ...............................................................................
1   
1   process/test/ProcessTests.cpp:59: FAILED:
1     REQUIRE( evt )
1   with expansion:
1     0
1   
1   <done>
1   ===============================================================================
1   test cases:   3 |   2 passed | 1 failed
1   assertions: 128 | 127 passed | 1 failed
1   
1   waiting for server to shut down.... done
1   server stopped
local:1/25/100%/5.6s parallel: This job failed:
runpart 1 'status should be replaced' 'LedgerTxnRoot prefetch' 'ItemFetcher fetches' 'subprocess fails' 'BitSet union'
FAIL: test/selftest-pg
==================
1 of 1 test failed
==================
```

I'm struggling to determine what this test is actually doing and why it's failing, could anyone explain or shed light? If not is there somewhere/someone better to ask?

My vague assumption is that it's either trying to perform some network operation that is going to work in the remote build chroot or consuming the memory allocation of the system perhaps.

Kind regards,
   Phil